# Cubism - Display of values in axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on Cubism chart. Whenever I scroll the mouse over it, it displays the time value also as in http://square.github.io/cubism/demo/

I dont want the time to be displayed on focus. But if only the intervals could display its value, thats enough.

If I say font size of axis as zero, even the interval values are not displayed. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the values that get displayed on the axis whenever the focus of mouse is over the axis. The change should be made in cubism.v1.

```
var format = context.step() < 6e4 ? cubism_axisFormatSeconds: context.step() < 864e5 ? cubism_axisFormatMinutes: cubism_axisFormatDays;
```

should be changed to the format that we need.

so when the format is used in the line,
    context.on("focus.axis" for changing the format during focus, it will get reflected.